# Yet another attempt to do the "vlookup" thing using AWK

Tags: awk, ksh

Just a clarifications before starting: The server where the script needs to run is an AIX box. Shell is KSH, so I do not have the advanced features Bash provides.

Ok, this is what I need to acccomplish:

I have two files. Both of them have two colums, separated by comma.

File "A" has ~170K lines, and it looks like this:

```
0000A7AED4F0C9FB1ADC14134700CadsevDDD4A000CEDCF.ext,\\server000005\F$\DICE\0035\
0000C3793C4CD6095947E44618D4Eadsev397460011D036.ext,\\server000005\F$\DICE\0020\
0001168DDDA4DF294E37753FE891BadsevB33900011EEA3.ext,\\server000005\F$\DICE\0088\
00014E6A3AFF0911D95A933778895adsev6C81E00088E97.ext,\\server000005\F$\DICE\0009\
0001A65FA90EC0E6640E1589C4B66adsev6FE1F00088EB9.ext,\\server000005\F$\DICE\0009\
0001C5AA0A9AC8E4EDFC69C483160adsev881CC001157ED.ext,\\server000005\F$\DICE\0034\
0003270ED2D2AB11739029711A233adsev55605000CFC63.ext,\\server000005\F$\DICE\0028\
000327C08A0ECD8F23EE6AE42B3C3adsevE35F00011481D.ext,\\server000005\F$\DICE\0061\
0003423C2592EF9D0AD9A7E2B595Cadsev6ABD9000D3501.ext,\\server000005\F$\DICE\0022\
00035862746EFB2098EC965F31328adsev66800000DA8CF.ext,\\server000005\F$\DICE\0021\
```

File "B" has ~2Million lines, and it looks like this:

```
0000294A3F3997slredA9D7ADBEE0C0CDE67C100001245C.nlo,\\server000002\F$\RESTORE_DICE\DICE\0083\
00003FFF21F5DAslred8F20FCF0A5CEE9920A4A00016835.nlo,\\server000002\F$\RESTORE_DICE\DICE\0029\
00005B1FFB996Fslred065F708695ADDD987AF9002139AD.nlo,\\server000002\F$\RESTORE_DICE\DICE\0157\
00005CF3C87456slred41FDB077914EB04FFA2B001F9D74.nlo,\\server000002\F$\RESTORE_DICE\DICE\0103\
00006BD33D737FslredD717F08A20F44F2B878500011050.nlo,\\server000002\F$\RESTORE_DICE\DICE\0094\
00008254F4D661slred6C05CFC91D9BCB82EDD800077FFA.nlo,\\server000002\F$\RESTORE_DICE\DICE\0082\
000092391392E3slredB744E98697FA39CEEDCD0004FB66.nlo,\\server000002\F$\RESTORE_DICE\DICE\0032\
0000945EDBB916slredAB08CD7AA8B825E1F55C0000FDC0.nlo,\\server000002\F$\RESTORE_DICE\DICE\0093\
0000C3793C4CD6slredE44618D4E0A2C50397460011D036.nlo,\\server000002\F$\RESTORE_DICE\DICE\0146\
0000D0DA56260DslredF30BCC9CDFF2A4556A7500039400.nlo,\\server000002\F$\RESTORE_DICE\DICE\0054\
```

In boh cases, column 1 is a filename while column 2 is it's path.

What I need:

for each line in file A, grab the filename, look for it in file B, and compose a newline, to be echoed/print into a new file "C" consisting of the following three fields:
Column 1: Path for the file as shown in file B.
Column 2: Path for the file as shown in file A.
Column 3: File name.

I have tried to keep it short as I have been "accused" of diarrhea of the words in previous questions, but feel free to let me know in case I am missing important details here.

Just so you know, I have working batch and ksh codes for this that work fine with smaller (lesser lines) files, tough none of them do the job in this case. (CMD Batch one only processes a couple thousand lines an hour, while the ksh one refuses to even read such files based on memory limitations..)

Thank you guys for being always there!

Martín.

Comment: Please share your research to solve the problem: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sort both files on key, then `join`

Comment: Glenn: I have looked for a solution within the site and even tried to modify the piece of code I was provided in a previous question ("Vlookup-like function using awk in ksh") but was not able to make them work. Unfortunately, my knowleadge of AWK does not go far beyond using it to isolate and print columns of a given input.

Comment: There is no special `vlookup`, it's the standard array indexing.  However, you need to store the file in memory for this operation.  `sort/join` will probably work better.

Comment: Tiw: You are right about the formating. I am in a hurry right now, but will upgrade it later (not that I do not like doing it, see my previous questions) if it is too infuriating.
Karakfa: I do not think that's gonna work (or would'n know how to do it) since the amount of lines in both files is not the same.

Comment: Once sorted, number of lines are irrelevant.  `man sort` and `man join` will give you all the information you need (and some more).

Comment: Thanks Karakfa. Join did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It's like 3 lines and a couple of temporary files if you don't have access to ksh93  (I think AIX uses ksh88, not ksh93?), bash, zsh, or another shell that understands `<(command)` redirection...

```
$ sort -t, -k1 filea > sorted_filea
$ sort -t, -k1 fileb > sorted_fileb
$ join -t, -j1 -o '2.2 1.2 0' sorted_filea sorted_fileb > filec
```

(fewer if one or both of the files are already sorted on filename.)

If you **do** have one of those shells:

```
$ join -t, -j1 -o '2.2 1.2 0' <(sort -t, -k1 filea) <(sort -t, -k1 fileb) > filec
```